# strtok string and modify token value

Tags: c++, strtok

hi im doing string tokenization similarly to the example below. however, within the while loop, i will be changing letter 'a' to 'hellow' for example. im getting segmentation fault when trying to change pch before assigning to myVar[i]. how should i go about doing it?

```
    map <int, char*> myVar;
    char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
    char * pch;
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
    int i = 0;

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);

        //modify token value
        stringstream strStream;
        strStream << "hello_world";

        char newStr[7] = {0};
        memcpy(newStr, strStream, 7);

        myVar[i] = (char*)newStr;
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
        i++;
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean "change pch"?

Comment: The code you posted isn't the code you're having the problem with (there's no change to the token). Post the code that *doesn't* work.

Comment: hey sorry guys, i've edited my code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two bugs inside of your `while` loop:

1) you are passing the `stringstream` itself, not the data it contains, to `memcpy()`.  You are relying on the `stringstream::operator void*()` conversion operator.  You are not supposed to deference that pointer, as it does not point at actual data.  It is merely a flag to indicate whether the `stringstream` is valid or not.  To pass the `stringstream` data to `memcpy()`, you have to call its `str()` method first to get a `std::string` containing the data, and then call its `c_str()` method to pass that data to `memcpy()`.

2) when you are inserting values into your `std::map`, you are inserting a local `char[]` variable each time.  That `char[]` goes out of scope immediately afterwards, leaving the `std::map` containing pointers to random locations on the stack.  Given the code you have shown, the `char[]` buffers are likely to reuse the same stack space each time.

Since you are using C++, you really should be using more C++-oriented things, like `std::string`, `std::cout`, etc.

Try this:

```
std::map <int, std::string> myVar;
std::string str = "- This, a sample string.";
std::cout << "Splitting string \"" << str << "\" into tokens:" << std::endl;
size_t start = 0;
int i = 0;

do
{
    std::string token;

    size_t pos = str.find_first_of(" ,.-", start);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    { 
        token = str.substr(start, pos-start);
        start = pos + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        token = str.substr(start);
        start = std::string::npos;
    }

    std::cout << token << std::endl;

    //modify token value
    myVar[i] = "hello_world";

    ++i;
 }
 while (start != std::string::npos);
```

Comment: Isn't it a no-no to modify the return value of a std::string.c_str() ? (as strtok does)

Comment: It IS a no-no to modify the value returned by c_str() as you have. It's clearly written in the docs. Quoting http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/: "The returned array points to an internal location with the required storage space for this sequence of characters plus its terminating null-character, but the values in this array should not be modified in the program and are only guaranteed to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object." +1 for the advice to do in c++ manner, -1 for error. Result 0.

Comment: Well, I DID say be should replace `strtok()`, afterall. That would eliminate the "modifying c_str()" issue...

Comment: Indeed - but you didn't say why. This is just the type of advice - (i.e that given without a reason as to why it should be followed) that is prone to being ignored by new users, on account of it 'introduces unnecessary complexity for no gain'. The explanation as to the reason is a much better way of teaching a man to fish. Failing to do so is more akin to handing a man a fish, in my opinion. Good answer overall, just a small oversight. :)

Answer (score 0):

You see, the thing is: strtok *modifies* the string passed to it. 
This often segfaults if you try to use it on a string constant, since the memory is not really yours to alter.

The method I use to get around this is to always use strtok on a *duplicate* of the string.

```
char *srcStr = "Some constant text";
char *tmpStr = strdup(srcStr);
//...
//some operations involving strtok
//...
free(tmpStr);
```